# How to determine if a camera flash is available on an iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone

Overall my app works on all iOS device however I have a feature that only works on iPhone 4's therefore if the user does not have an iPhone 4 I'd like to display an alert letting them know that this feature won't work on their device?

How can I do that?

I'm trying to check if the device has the camera-flash

Comment: What specific feature do you require?

Comment: I require the camera-flash for this feature

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried the various [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) methods? That said, there's most likely an easier way, depending on what specific feature your optional functionality requires, but without knowing what this is it's hard to give a concrete example.

**N.B.: I'd also recommend not presuming a feature set based on the detected device itself for reasons of future compatibility.**

**UPDATE**

In terms of the camera flash, I know you can use the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)'s isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice: method. (You'll probably want to call this after first verifying the existance of a camera via the isCameraDeviceAvailable: method.)

Comment: Checking for a specific device is almost never the right answer, you should usually check for the presence/absence of a feature.

Comment: @Kuba - Yup, was editing my answer to say precisely that when you left your message, which is why I asked the OP on my comment attached to the question. :-)

Comment: i'm trying to check if they have a camera-flash

Comment: would I get an error if I created an instance of the camera on a device that does not have one? (i.e ipads, older ipod touches, etc)...it seems I to create an instance of the camera and pass it into the method.

Comment: @cgossain - Use the isCameraDeviceAvailable method first.

Comment: @cgossain - Glad to be of help. Best of luck with the app. :-)

Answer (score 11):

If you aren't using `UIImagePicker`:

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
BOOL hasFlash = [device hasFlash];
```

There is also a `[device hasTorch]` if you need it.

Comment: Don't forget to `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to know what device you're running on, check to see if the feature you want to use is available and display an alert if it isn't.

If you let us know what specific feature you're looking for, we can help with the specific way to check for that feature.

Though, my own advice here, popping up a dialog box that says, "If you had a newer phone, you'd be able to do *this!*" is really just rubbing your user's face in the fact that they've got an older phone, now isn't it? A better way to handle it would be to 1) make it clear in your AppStore page that certain features won't be available on non iPhone 4 phones and 2) make your app's behavior degrade gracefully on non iPhone 4s.

Comment: i'm trying to check if they have a camera-flash

Comment: +1 Have to agree - there's not a lot of value in telling a user something they can't do. This is best dealt with in the marketing blurb.

Answer (score 2):

For swift 4.0

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)
         var hasFlash: Bool! = false
         hasFlash = device?.hasFlash
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little dusty but if you come across it, here is some current information.

First, you can require that the device have a flash via the following value for `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in your `info.plist` file.

```
camera-flash
```

> Include this key if your app requires (or specifically
>   prohibits) the presence of a camera flash for taking pictures or
>   shooting video. Apps use the UIImagePickerController interface to
>   control the enabling of this feature.

[Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1388988-hasflash?changes=_9)

Next, you can check your `UIImagePickerController` to see if one is available. This is useful as not every camera on every device has a flash.

```
isFlashAvailable(for:)
```

> Indicates whether a given camera has flash illumination capability.

[Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619118-isflashavailable?changes=_8)

Or, if you are using `AVFoundation`, you can query the `AVCaptureDevice`:

```
captureDevice.hasFlash
```

> Indicates whether the capture device has a flash.

[Documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1388988-hasflash?changes=_9)

Answer (score -1):

Solution in Objective-C:

```
- (bool)hasDeviceLED {
    bool hasFlash = NO;
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if (device != nil) {
        hasFlash = device.hasFlash;
    }

    return hasFlash;
}
```

Successfully tested with iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Effectively identical to existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745109/341994